# Perimeter of a Triangle calculation in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, procedure

Does anyone understand this task (in Dr Racket) which wants to write a procedure triangle-perimeter which calculates the perimeter
of a triangle. The procedure should take as an input a representation of rectangular triangles.
Implement such a representation make-triangle which uses as an input the
three coordinates of the corner of the triangle (0,0) (2,0) (0,2).

It's really hard to understand...
Any advice is appreciated!
Best Regards, Eunice

Comment: You're supposed to write a `make-triangle` procedure that constructs a triangle for your chosen representation, and then, when given one such triangle, calculate its perimeter using the `triangle-perimeter` procedure. We can't help you any further, as this looks like a homework - but if you have any specific questions regarding your code, don't hesitate to ask them, please don't forget to post the code first.

Comment: The context of the exercise is missing. Have you previously solved an exercise with distance between two points? If so reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

All it takes is working out the length of each side and then summing the lengths:

```
(define (perimiter a b c d e f)
    (let ([side1 (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b)))]
          [side2 (sqrt (+ (* c c) (* d d)))]
          [side3 (sqrt (+ (* e e) (* f f)))])
        (+ side1 side2 side3)))

(write (perimiter 0 0 0 2 2 0))
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to spoon-feed answers to people looking to get their homework done for free...